# Hearing clickings at the beginning and after jfugue pattern

Tags: java, jfugue

Making the first steps with jfugue... Pretty easy!

But at the beginning and after the pattern I hear small clicks(pops).
It is very important to me avoid them. 
Working on Windows with Eclipse

```
import org.jfugue.*; 

public class PlayFreq 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String A2 =  "X[Volume]=10200 T120 I54 Rq G9i Rq F9q. Rq";
    Player player = new Player(); 
    Pattern ptr_a2 = new Pattern(A2);

    player.play(" Rq G9 Rq");

    System.exit(0); // If using Java 1.4 or lower 
    } 
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Here is little "miscoding" : player.plays string and not predefined pattern ptr_a2. But in both cases I hear the pops

Comment: Are you using the "Deluxe Soundbank" available here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/soundbanks-135798.html - if not, give that a try and see if it stops the pops. There is nothing in JFugue itself that would create pops; this is probably an issue with the MIDI synthesizer that your JRE is using.

Comment: Of course I am using deluxe!